# exporting a pointer to class for a dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static, dllexport

I am not clear how to Dll-export a pointer to a static / thread_local variable. My problem looks as follows (all on Windows (using MSVC 2015))

I have in my "projectLibrary" project

pointer to thread_local variable

```
class ToBeExported;
extern thread_local ToBeExported* toBeExportedCurrentThread;
```

the main class (with DLL export)

```
class __declspec(dllexport) ToBeExported
{
public:
  ToBeExported(int m) : m_(m) {}

private:
  int m_;  
};
```

I have another class that uses toBeExportedCurrentThread in its implementation

```
template<typename T> 
class UserToBeExported
{
...
}
```

In my client project "projectClient" I use UserToBeExported

```
UserToBeExported u; 
u.use();
```

but this leads to an LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "class ToBeExported* toBeExportedCurrentThread"

I have tried playing with __declspec(dllexport) on the pointer variable, but to no avail. Anyone know what the rules are for static / thread_local variable exporting on Windows?

Cheers, Mike

Comment: I assume you are defining `toBeExportedCurrentThread` in one place, and declare (use) it in another one. What are the exact  declaration in both places ?